# Can I find all curly-braceless if-statements in my team's code?

Tags: if-statement, phpstorm, curly-braces

In my company we have coding styles, that include always using curly braces with an if-statement, so:

```
// instead of this...
if (condition)
  doThis();

// we want this
if (condition) {
  doThis();
}
```

Now not everyone has done this since the start and we would like to clean up and make the code more consistent. Is there a way (with PHPStorm preferably) to find all braceless if-statements?

Comment: Use PHP_CodeSniffer rules for that? PhpStorm has integration with this tool. I have not used it myself, but maybe you can configure it to report only that specific issue (or just run trough all reported issues and find only those that you are interested in). https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Sniffer+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Another alternative is to try **Structural Search** (`Edit | Find | Find Structurally`) -- in theory it could be able to do that, not sure though.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne for your suggestion. However, Nate B's answer below is easier for my purpose. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a regular expression search as follows:

Edit > Find > Find in Path

Search for the string `if\s*\(.+\)[^{\S]*\n`, and be sure that the Regular expression checkbox is active.

This technique isn't perfect, as it will yield false positives for conditionals spanning multiple lines (such that their opening brace is on line 2, 3, etc...).   But it can accurately distinguish between simple single-line conditionals, like the two you provided in your question.

Comment: Great, I don't need something very advanced, as I won't be doing this too often, so those little false positives aren't that bad. However, it doesn't work when the condition is not just a boolean. Like `if (a != b)` or `if (!confirm("Sure?"))`. Mind updating that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have python installed, you can run following program, I wrote for you, to find all such lines in your code: (tested on python27)

run as :

```
 python bracketless.py yourfile
```

```
import sys,re
fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname) as f:
    if_block = False
    lnum = 0        
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if (re.search(r'\bif\b', line)) and not '{' in line:
            if_block = True
            lnum = i+1 
            if ';' in line:
                print 'Found bracketless if in line {}'.format(lnum)
                if_block = False
        elif if_block:
            if '{' in line:
                if_block = False
            elif ';' in line:
                print 'Found bracketless if in line {}'.format(lnum)
                if_block = False
```

Comment: Hey @K246, works like a charm, thanks, though it is a bit overkill for my purpose. :-) (and it doesn't skip comments)

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply use PhpStorm's built in code style tools for this. If you go to File -> Settings and then to Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces you can set force braces for if/for/foreach/while/do...while to 'always'. Braces will then automatically be added when reformatting your code.

However, this approach obviously has the "side effect" of applying all other formatting rules as well. That may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: HEy @chocochaos, it's not, but it sure is helpful! Thanks.